# Pentaho Kettle transformation update: how to use ignore lookup failure

Tags: oracle, pentaho, transformation, kettle, insert-update

How Ignore lookup Failure works in Kettle Transformation UPDATE step? I have transformation trying to update some data but I see frequent error message in this step when key look up doesn't match with table data.

[image]

Comment: I've never used Pentaho but for the benefit of those that do, do you currently have it ticked? if not, when you do tick it what happens? What is the error message? Now when a Pentaho expert comes by there might be enough info for them to help.

Comment: What happens when you check the checkbox? I suspect nothing, meaning the failed lookup row is silently discarded. I don't use that checkbox myself because I always handle these things upstream, but it might make sense for you.

Answer (score 2):

By default the `Update step` looks up a record (from database) according to keys (IDs) defined in `Keys to look up the values` panel. If no record is found in the target table the step fails and throws an error to console. It fails because it tries to compare looked up values from target table with values from record stream. If it does not find any row from target database for comparing, it fails.

When you check `Ignore lookup failures?` the step does not fail. It ignores particular failures and keeps processing another incoming rows from record stream.

You can use `Flag field` to keep an information whether the lookup failed or not. You can use it to track all IDs which failed and write them out to the console or file.

E.g: The step is useful when your ETL loads daily increments from a source to a target database. The source database already contains daily increments [`IDs: 1,2,3,4,5,6`] while target contains only those loaded before [`IDs: 1,2,3,4`]. Now when you run a transformation which loads data from the source and updates the target (using `Update step`), it fails on `ID = 5`. It cannot lookup such a record in the target database.

Another important option is `Skip lookup`. When it is checked it directly executes update statements without looking up rows in target database and comparing table values with incoming values from record stream.